# I tried creating lag variable for a momentum plan but not sure how to proceed

Tags: momentum

this is how I sorted for lag variables data

```
tsset permno date, monthly 
sort permno date
by permno: gen lagret1=ret[_n-1]
by permno: gen lagret2=ret[_n-2]
by permno: gen lagret3=ret[_n-3]
by permno: gen lagret4=ret[_n-4]
by permno: gen lagret5=ret[_n-5]
```

i don't know the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
*Step 1: Upload the data and create key variables

*Upload the dataset that contains CRSP information and create key variables.

use "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/CRSPforMOM.dta", clear

*Keep only common stock
keep if shrcd == 10 | shrcd == 11

*Create monthindex variable
gen monthindex = year(date)*12+month(date)

*Create past 5 months of returns using lag function
*in order to use the built- in lag function I need to tell stata the 
*structure of the data
tsset permno date, monthly 
sort permno date
by permno: gen lagret1=ret[_n-1]
by permno: gen lagret2=ret[_n-2]
by permno: gen lagret3=ret[_n-3]
by permno: gen lagret4=ret[_n-4]
by permno: gen lagret5=ret[_n-5]

*Create a variable that captures cumulative retruns of stock i, 
*from month -5 through current month

*Compounding requires multiplying consecutive returns
gen cumret6 = (1+ret)*(1+lagret1)*(1+lagret2)*(1+lagret3)*(1+lagret4)*        (1+lagret5)

*Save
save "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM1.dta", replace

*Step 2: Create and apply filters
*Before allocating stocks to portfolios, we should create and apply filters

*Select only NYSE stocks and find the 10th percentil of NYSE size in each month
use "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM1.dta", clear

*Keep only NYSE stocks
keep if exchcd == 1

*Keep if market cap is larger than 0
keep if mktcap >0

*Drop missing observations where marketcap is missing
drop if missing(mktcap)

*Since we create portfolios monthly, we need breakpoints monthly
sort date
by date: egen p10=pctile(mktcap), p(10)

*We only need date variable (for merging) and p10 variable (as a filter),
*so we drop everything else
keep date p10

*Drop duplicates so that p10 repeats once for every month in the sample
duplicates drop

*save
save "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOMNYSEBreakpoints.dta",     replace

*Merge the breakpoints into the dataset created in step 1, 
*so that we can remove small firms

*Break points are date specific so merge on date

use "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM1.dta", clear
sort date
merge m:1 date using "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOMNYSEBreakpoints.dta"

*merge==3 indicates that an observation is present in both
*master and using datasets, that is the only data that is properly merged 
*and the only data that should be kept
```

keep if _merge==3

```
*We need to drop _merge variable to be able to merge data again
```

drop _merge

```
*Apply filters, i.e. remove small firms and firms priced below $5
```

drop if missing(mktcap)
drop if mktcap<=p10
    *use absolute value because CRSP denotes BID-ASK midpoint with negative sign
drop if abs(prc)<5

```
*Save
```

save "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM2.dta", replace

```
*Step 3: Allocate stocks in 10 portfolios and hold for 6 months

*Use new file
use "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM2.dta", clear
```

sort  date

```
*We will create variable prret6, which will tell us which portfolio a stock
*belongs to based on cumret 6

*We will use command xtile puts a prespecified percent of firms into 
*each portfolio

*nq() tells stata how many portfolios we want
by date: egen prret6 = xtile (cumret6), nq(10) // takes ~20min to run

*Save
save "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM3.dta", replace

*Use the portfolios
use "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM3.dta", clear
drop if missing(prret6)

*Expand data, i.e. create 6 copies of the data
```

expand 6

```
sort permno date

*Create variable n which trackswhat copy of the data it is, 
*n will go from 1 to 6

*_n is the count for the dataset/ the number for each observation
by permno date: gen n=_n

*Use n variable to increment monthindex by 1
replace monthindex = monthindex+n

sort permno monthindex

*Drop return from the master dataset because we want the one from the 
*using dataset
drop ret

merge m:1 permno monthindex using "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM1.dta"


keep if _merge==3
drop _merge

save "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM4.dta", replace
*Step 4: Analysis
use "/Users/dk/Desktop/USD Documents/MSF/MFIN 518/MOM4.dta", clear


sort monthindex prret6 date

*Average returns based on each portfolio in each calendar month and by
*formation month
collapse (mean) ret, by (monthindex prret6 date)

*Summarize again to get average portfolio returns by calendar month     (monthindex)
collapse (mean) ret, by (monthindex prret6)

*Transpose the data
reshape wide ret, i(monthindex) j(prret6) // i(rows) j(columns)

*Generate year and month variable for clarity
gen year= round(monthindex/12)
gen month=(monthindex-year*12)+6

*create momentum return variable and check for significance
gen momret=ret10-ret1
ttest ret10=ret1


*testing momentum returns from year 2000 onward
keep if monthindex>=24000
ttest ret10=ret1
```